# MonoGame Mac Templates Installation

Tags: c#, macos, mono, monodevelop, monogame

I am having trouble installing the MonoGame templates in MonoDevelop on Mac. I have placed the MonoDevelop.MonoGame.2.5 folder in MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/ as instructed by the readme but after restarting monodevlop, the template is not available in the new projects section. Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Mac templates should be available in the 2.5.1 bug fix release, due soon.